# Find value within a range of cells and return a value a certain distance away

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a series of pages with "product code" fields that I am copying from my website (the original source document has been misplaced). I now have the page data in excel and need to use a formula to find the heading "Product Code" and then return the value that is under that heading. Though the headings are consistent between pages, each page is a bit different in terms of where on the page that value is.

I need to work out the best formula so that regardless of which cell the "Product code" is in, excel can find it and then give the value of the cell below it.

It seems straight forward but I just can't get it and it's doing my head in. I have looked elsewhere and can't seem to rework other people's examples that use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, MATCH & INDEX formulas.

Does anyone know how this would be possible?

Comment: is it directly below? do you want an excel function, specifically or VBA ok?

Comment: Hi @RusanKax, yes the relevant field is always directly under the "Product Code" cell. Preferably excel formula if possible, but happy to learn how to use macros if totally necessary. :)

Comment: One more question - is there always only 1 *unique* cell containing the text you want to find on each sheet?

Comment: yep, always only one reference to the product code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest and most flexible way is to use a VBA function (that you can simply use as it were a normal worksheet function). Here is the VBA

```
Public Function Find_Pcode(ByRef to_search As Range, Findthat As String) As Variant
    Find_Pcode = to_search.Find(what:=Findthat, MatchCase:=False).Offset(1, 0).Value
End Function
```

If you really want to/have to use built-in worksheet functions, it is a bit fiddly if you do not know what columns or rows your label "Product Code" will be in.

If you do know the ROW, for instance, then it can be done like this:

`=OFFSET(G5,1,MATCH("Product Code",G5:O5,0)-1)`

where `G5` is the first cell in the row `G5:O5` which you know contains the cell with "Product Code" in it. As I mentioned, this only works if you know which row to look at.

Also, if you know it will always be in Column A, for instance, then you can also use this worksheet function

`=OFFSET(A1,MATCH("Product Code",A1:A25,0),0)`

Where `A1:A25` is where you want to search for the cell containing "Product Code".

The pictures below detail how to use the functions (might have to zoom in!)

To use the VBA. Open VBA window -> insert "Module" in your worksheet (via left pane and right click on worksheet name) -> paste the VBA into the module -> use VBA like in picture 2.

The VBA is more flexible, as you can give it a square/any-size range to search.

[image: how to use match]

[image: how to use VBA function]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this @RusanKax, very much appreciated. 

I know that the column will always be 'A', the inconsistency is in how far down the column it will be each time. Does that make it easier to use an excel formula?

To use the VBA function, I'll have to learn how to use macros (that's okay but will take me longer obviously.. :])

Comment: @EKQM no problems. Please come again